# Function call from a function pointer to another member function gives "Uncaught TypeError: is not a function"

Tags: javascript, function-pointers

I am trying to use an array of functions in a JavaScript object to easily display a maze.  But my call from the function array gives "Uncaught TypeError: is not a function".  How would I fix this issue?

Here is what I trying to do in my javascript app, it is pretty straighforward:

```
var cells = [
    [4, 6, 14, 14, 12],
    [3, 0, 11, 10, 11],
    [14, 6, 14, 14, 10],
    [4, 3, 2, 14, 12],
    [4, 6, 5, 14, 7],
    [4, 6, 14, 8, 12]
];

var m = new Maze();

m.draw(cells);
```

Basically I would like to provide a two dimensional array with cell codes to my Maze object, and it should just draw those cells on screen.  And here is my class implementation:

```
function Maze() {
    this.ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // array of functions
    this.draw_cells = [
        this.draw_cell_0,
        this.draw_cell_1,
        this.draw_cell_2,
        this.draw_cell_3,
        this.draw_cell_4,
        this.draw_cell_5,
        this.draw_cell_6,
        this.draw_cell_7,
        this.draw_cell_8,
        this.draw_cell_9,
        this.draw_cell_10,
        this.draw_cell_11,
        this.draw_cell_12,
        this.draw_cell_13,
        this.draw_cell_14,
        this.draw_cell_15
    ];
}

Maze.prototype.draw_background = function(col, row) {
    this.ctx.fillRect(...);
};


Maze.prototype.draw_cell_0 = function(col, row) {
    this.draw_background(col, row);
    ...
};

...

Maze.prototype.draw_cell_15 = function(col, row) {
    this.draw_background(col, row);
    ...
};


Maze.prototype.draw = function(cells) {
    for (var row=0; row < cells.length; row++) {
        var rowCells = cells[row];
        for (var col = 0; col < rowCells.length; col++) {
            var cellCode = rowCells[col];
            this.draw_cells[cellCode](col, row);
        }
    }
};
```

So my class has a variable holding an array of functions, each pointing to a draw_cell method based on its code name.  I have 16 different types of cells can be drawn.  Each draw_cell_### function also calls a common draw_background function.

However, when I run this on my browser, it gives:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.draw_background is not a function
    at Array.Maze.draw_cell_4 (maze.js:110)
    at Maze.draw (maze.js:220)
    at init (test.html:28)
    at onload (test.html:106)
```

So it seems calling an indexed function from my array is working, but during the function call runtime, it doesn't recognize another member function of the same class.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: `this.draw_cells[cellCode](col, row)` is a method call on the `this.draw_cells` object, not on `this`.

Comment: @melpomene How would I fix it? I am a bit not sure what that implies.

Comment: Why do you have 16 separate draw_cell_n functions?

Comment: @melpomene  They draw different cells.  There are 16 different variant of cells.

Comment: @melpomene  So my end goal is to display any maze I like by supplying a two dimensional array of cell codes.

Comment: When you attach your functionpointers, use .bind(this). This will ensure, that the function context is you maze.

Comment: @KaiLehmann  Where exactly do I bind(this)?

Comment: this.draw_cells = [ this.draw_cell_0.bind(this), ... For more information check https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: @KaiLehmann  That is a beauty!  It now works!  Thx!